# Developing App for Android TV - SVG Text Pixelated and Blurry on 4K TV

Tags: android, svg, react-native, android-tv

I am desperate for some advice designing for Android TV. Specially in regards to getting an SVG interface to display clear and crisp on a 4K television.

The SVG interface is a family tree design. The size of the text in the tree has to be 11px due to the amount of names needed to be shown. So the text is very small. However it is created using the SVG  element. Therefore it should scale without issue.

My first attempt was at using a WebView to display the SVG. I later found out that the WebView component will not display SVG data clear crisp. The text is very much pixelated.

My latest attempt was using React Native and the SVG library. Again the SVG text is appearing quite pixelated.

My head is spinning a bit trying to understand how my App is being displayed / upscaled.
I'm a bit confused because when I use the React function: useWindowDimensions().width;
It is reporting back 960 no matter what. Shouldn't it be 3840 when displayed using the 4K Chromecast?

I can't wrap my head around why SVG text is getting pixelated on a 4K television when using the Google Chromecast w/4K.

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67830848/edit) your post to clarify your testing setup, and how you are sending what content to display. You mention Android TV and Chromecast which are two different APIs/devices.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am developing an Android App using React Native. I debug the app on my desktop using Android TV simulator via the Android Studio / AVD Manager.  I then bundle the app and install the APK on my Google Chromecast which is connected to my 50" 4K television. When the app is viewed on the television the text is not clear and crisp as I would expect.

Comment: I would test with a few different font sizes to make sure the app is not scaling some built-in font to 11pt.

Comment: Android TV UI is based on 1920x1080 and scaled to the panel's resolution. You can run `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger` to see how your panel is being recognized, though it sounds like useWindowDimensions().width is returning the value in DP (ATV is XHDPI, so 2x960dp==1920px). 11px is REALLY tiny for a TV which will cause accessibility issues and may be the reason the pixelation is more prominent (I'm assuming the SVG is rasterized at 11px and then upscaled to the panel dimensions).

Comment: As Ian pointed out and from what I read it's the way Android TV UI works. It's based on 1920 X 1080. One would assume that means any apps displayed in the UI will also show at that resolution. The pixels would then be scaled up. I guess I always thought the SVG would scale properly. However it isn't really the SVG being scaled, it's the pixels that are being scaled up. I went out and bought an Nvidia Shield Pro and enabled the developers mode so I could adb connect to it. I then ran the command: wm size 3840x2160 to force it to use 4K. After doing that things displayed much better.

Comment: Unfortunately I am trying to create a marketable product. Asking people to buy a specialized piece of hardware, ie the Nvidia Shield Pro, and then enabling these special modes isn't going to work. I hoped the Google Chromecast 4K was going to work. I believe it may be best to wait and see if Google updates the Android TV UI to be 4K. I originally started this project out on the web and running it on a Raspberry PI which outputs at 4K. The SVG interface looks absolutely brilliant on there. I had high hopes when I started this project that Android TV would work for.